# Parsing an IP routing report with half a million lines into a PANDAS dataframe

Tags: python, performance, parsing, pandas, ip-address

I have a file that has around 440K lines of data. I need to read these data and find the actual "table" in the text file. Part of the text file looks like this.

```
[BEGIN] 2022/4/8 14:00:05
<Z0301IPBBPE03>screen-length 0 temporary                          
Info: The configuration takes effect on the current user terminal interface only.
<Z0301IPBBPE03>display bgp vpnv4 vpn-instance Charging_VRF routing-table
 
 BGP Local router ID is 10.12.24.19
 Status codes: * - valid, > - best, d - damped, x - best external, a - add path,
               h - history,  i - internal, s - suppressed, S - Stale
               Origin : i - IGP, e - EGP, ? - incomplete
 RPKI validation codes: V - valid, I - invalid, N - not-found

    
 VPN-Instance Charging_VRF, Router ID 10.12.24.19:

 Total Number of Routes: 2479
        Network            NextHop                       MED        LocPrf    PrefVal Path/Ogn

 *>i    10.0.19.0/24       10.12.8.21                     0          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.8.22                     0          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.0.143.0/24      10.12.8.21                     0          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.8.22                     0          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.0.144.128/25    10.12.8.21                     0          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.8.22                     0          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.0.148.80/32     10.12.8.21                     0          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.8.22                     0          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.0.148.81/32     10.12.8.21                     0          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.8.22                     0          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.0.201.16/28     10.12.8.21                     0          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.8.22                     0          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.0.201.64/29     10.12.8.21                     0          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.8.22                     0          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.0.201.94/32     10.12.8.21                     0          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.8.22                     0          100        0       ?
...
<Z0301IPBBPE03>display bgp vpnv4 vpn-instance Gb_VRF routing-table
 
 BGP Local router ID is 10.12.24.19
 Status codes: * - valid, > - best, d - damped, x - best external, a - add path,
               h - history,  i - internal, s - suppressed, S - Stale
               Origin : i - IGP, e - EGP, ? - incomplete
 RPKI validation codes: V - valid, I - invalid, N - not-found

    
 VPN-Instance Gb_VRF, Router ID 10.12.24.19:

 Total Number of Routes: 1911
        Network            NextHop                       MED        LocPrf    PrefVal Path/Ogn

 *>i    10.1.133.192/30    10.12.8.63                     0          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.8.63                     0          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.1.133.216/30    10.12.8.64                     0          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.8.64                     0          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.1.160.248/29    10.12.40.7                     0          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.40.7                     0          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.1.161.0/29      10.12.40.8                     0          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.40.8                     0          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.1.161.248/32    10.12.40.7                     2          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.40.7                     2          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.1.161.249/32    10.12.40.7                     2          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.40.7                     2          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.1.164.248/29    10.12.40.7                     0          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.40.7                     0          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.1.165.0/29      10.12.40.8                     0          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.40.8                     0          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.1.165.248/32    10.12.40.7                     2          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.40.7                     2          100        0       ?
```

The text file goes long way, and it has plenty of garbage lines which I did not want to, so I am trying to find the keywords (display bgp vpnv4 vpn-instance) and start reading once I found. The code looks like this, which I will convert the table into my dataframe.

My problem is that, reading this 440k lines of code and convert into dataframe takes me almost half an hour to complete, I am here to seek help to see if there is a better way to improve the efficiency.

```
import pandas as pd
import ipaddress
from chardet import detect


def validate_ipaddress(ip_address):
    try:
        ip = ipaddress.IPv4Network(ip_address)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def get_encoding_type(file):
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()
    return detect(data)['encoding']

bgp_df = pd.DataFrame()
vrf_list = ['Charging_VRF', 'Gb_VRF', 'Gn_VRF']
    
def generate_bgp_network_list(block, vrf):
    ip_address_list = block.split('\n')
    ip_addresses = [[address for address in ip_address.strip().split(' ') if address] for ip_address in ip_address_list if ip_address] # generate list of lines
    ip_addresses = [address for address in ip_addresses if len(address) > 0]        # remove empty list
    ip_addresses = [(ipaddress.IPv4Network(ip_address[1], False), ip_address[-1]) for ip_address in ip_addresses if validate_ipaddress(ip_address[1])]

    bgp_data = [{'ip_network': address, 'vrf': vrf, 'as_number': as_number} for address, as_number in ip_addresses]
    bgp_df = bgp_df.append(bgp_data, index=False)

def read_bgp_file(file):
    if file == '':
        return


    file = open(file, encoding=get_encoding_type(file))
    lines = file.readlines()
    start = False
    block = ''
    lines = iter(lines)
    for line in lines:
        if '<' in line and len(block) > 0:
            generate_bgp_network_list(block, vrf)
            start = False
            block = ''
        if f'display bgp vpnv4 vpn-instance' in line:
            vrf = line.strip().split(' ')[-2]
            if vrf in vrf_list:
                start = True
        if start:
            block += line
```

Comment: Hello and welcome on CR! Please post the full/working code such as: all the imports (`pandas`, `ipaddress`, etc), all variables / functions (`data`, `validate_ipaddress()`, `get_encoding_type()`) as well as how you are using your code (how you call your main function). Otherwise, this question will be closed because the code can't be run as it is.

Comment: What is the size of the file in bytes? Does it fit into your RAM?

Comment: @Reinderien I would expect ~500K lines to fit into any decent RAM ^^

Comment: @GrajdeanuAlex that depends on the line size. Some kinds of logs are aggressive in escaping breaks.

Comment: I think you could make your title more descriptive.  I doubt that "slow processing" is part of the code's purpose; "_processing_" and "_list_" are very generic - could you be more specific?  That might attract the more experienced reviewers to your question.  As a start, it seems that you're reading routing-table data, though I'm not sure what you're then using it for.

Comment: updated with full working code. The file size is around 40mb large. And yes, I am reading routing table data logged from a device. Which I need the data to process for other functions.

Comment: Crucially your excerpt does not show the _end_ of the table, only an ellipsis. Can you include this please?

Comment: It would help if you show the expected result, given the data above.

Answer (score 1):

For mid- to large-scale file processing, probably best to operate on string slices directly instead of lines.

`bgp_df` should not be a global, and should not be mutated by `generate_bgp_network_list`. But also: does your code actually work? You need to declare that variable as a global for your assignment to have any effect. Also, `index` is not a valid kwarg for `append`; [perhaps you're looking for `ignore_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html).

Much of your code misses the point of Pandas: it makes many annoying things easy, and you should always Google whether it's able to Do Your Thing before you do it yourself. [`read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) works perfectly with your data in inference mode and removes much of your manual parsing. You may or may not find a performance improvement when passing explicit colspecs.

`vrf_list` should be a set `{}` and not a list `[]`.

### Suggested

This does not cover address validation. As with everything performance: don't take my word for it; test and profile.

```
from io import StringIO
from typing import Iterator

import pandas as pd


vrf_list = {'Charging_VRF', 'Gb_VRF', 'Gn_VRF'}


def generate_bgp_network_list(block: str, vrf: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    with StringIO(block) as f:
        df = pd.read_fwf(f)

    df['vrf'] = vrf
    df = df.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0', 'NextHop', 'MED', 'LocPrf', 'PrefVal'])
    df = df[df.Network.notna()]
    return df.rename(columns={'Network': 'ip_network', 'Path/Ogn': 'as_number'})


def read_blocks(content: str) -> Iterator[pd.DataFrame]:
    routes_end = 0
    vpn_prefix = 'display bgp vpnv4 vpn-instance '
    routes_prefix = 'Total Number of Routes'

    while True:
        vpn_start = content.find(vpn_prefix, routes_end)
        if vpn_start == -1:
            break

        vrf_start = vpn_start + len(vpn_prefix)
        vrf_end = content.find(' ', vrf_start)
        vrf = content[vrf_start: vrf_end]

        routes_start = 1 + content.find(
            '\n',
            content.find(routes_prefix, vrf_end)
        )
        routes_end = content.find('\n<', routes_start)
        routes = content[routes_start: routes_end]

        yield generate_bgp_network_list(routes, vrf)


def read_bgp_file(content: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return pd.concat(
        tuple(read_blocks(content)),
        ignore_index=True,
    )


def main() -> None:
    content = '''[BEGIN] 2022/4/8 14:00:05
<Z0301IPBBPE03>screen-length 0 temporary                          
Info: The configuration takes effect on the current user terminal interface only.
<Z0301IPBBPE03>display bgp vpnv4 vpn-instance Charging_VRF routing-table
 
 BGP Local router ID is 10.12.24.19
 Status codes: * - valid, > - best, d - damped, x - best external, a - add path,
               h - history,  i - internal, s - suppressed, S - Stale
               Origin : i - IGP, e - EGP, ? - incomplete
 RPKI validation codes: V - valid, I - invalid, N - not-found

    
 VPN-Instance Charging_VRF, Router ID 10.12.24.19:

 Total Number of Routes: 2479
        Network            NextHop                       MED        LocPrf    PrefVal Path/Ogn

 *>i    10.0.19.0/24       10.12.8.21                     0          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.8.22                     0          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.0.143.0/24      10.12.8.21                     0          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.8.22                     0          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.0.144.128/25    10.12.8.21                     0          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.8.22                     0          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.0.148.80/32     10.12.8.21                     0          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.8.22                     0          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.0.148.81/32     10.12.8.21                     0          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.8.22                     0          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.0.201.16/28     10.12.8.21                     0          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.8.22                     0          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.0.201.64/29     10.12.8.21                     0          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.8.22                     0          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.0.201.94/32     10.12.8.21                     0          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.8.22                     0          100        0       ?

<Z0301IPBBPE03>display bgp vpnv4 vpn-instance Gb_VRF routing-table
 
 BGP Local router ID is 10.12.24.19
 Status codes: * - valid, > - best, d - damped, x - best external, a - add path,
               h - history,  i - internal, s - suppressed, S - Stale
               Origin : i - IGP, e - EGP, ? - incomplete
 RPKI validation codes: V - valid, I - invalid, N - not-found

    
 VPN-Instance Gb_VRF, Router ID 10.12.24.19:

 Total Number of Routes: 1911
        Network            NextHop                       MED        LocPrf    PrefVal Path/Ogn

 *>i    10.1.133.192/30    10.12.8.63                     0          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.8.63                     0          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.1.133.216/30    10.12.8.64                     0          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.8.64                     0          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.1.160.248/29    10.12.40.7                     0          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.40.7                     0          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.1.161.0/29      10.12.40.8                     0          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.40.8                     0          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.1.161.248/32    10.12.40.7                     2          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.40.7                     2          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.1.161.249/32    10.12.40.7                     2          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.40.7                     2          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.1.164.248/29    10.12.40.7                     0          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.40.7                     0          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.1.165.0/29      10.12.40.8                     0          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.40.8                     0          100        0       ?
 *>i    10.1.165.248/32    10.12.40.7                     2          100        300     ?
 * i                       10.12.40.7                     2          100        0       ?
 
 <'''

    bgp_df = read_bgp_file(content)
    print(bgp_df)
    '''
            ip_network           vrf as_number
    0     10.0.19.0/24  Charging_VRF         ?
    1    10.0.143.0/24  Charging_VRF         ?
    2  10.0.144.128/25  Charging_VRF         ?
    3   10.0.148.80/32  Charging_VRF         ?
    4   10.0.148.81/32  Charging_VRF         ?
    5   10.0.201.16/28  Charging_VRF         ?
    6   10.0.201.64/29  Charging_VRF         ?
    7   10.0.201.94/32  Charging_VRF         ?
    0  10.1.133.192/30        Gb_VRF         ?
    1  10.1.133.216/30        Gb_VRF         ?
    2  10.1.160.248/29        Gb_VRF         ?
    3    10.1.161.0/29        Gb_VRF         ?
    4  10.1.161.248/32        Gb_VRF         ?
    5  10.1.161.249/32        Gb_VRF         ?
    6  10.1.164.248/29        Gb_VRF         ?
    7    10.1.165.0/29        Gb_VRF         ?
    8  10.1.165.248/32        Gb_VRF         ?
    '''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The snippet posted here is only for testing purpose, just to see what is the best solution to speed up the whole thing. Anyway thanks for the suggestion, I actually had a solution where I can ignore the "generate_bgp_network_list" function cause that one is the culprit that slow down the whole process